# Using object.convert function after creating object

Tags: python, conversion

I'm creating an object from code

```
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("ObjectName", SomeMeshData)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Now, i want to convert this object into a Curve, using blender console i can see it's quite simple: `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE')` from code this doesn't work causing: `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.convert.poll()`

Using `obj.convert(target='CURVE')` causes different error:

`AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'convert'`

Should i 'select' the object and then use this function? This doesn't sound like proper approach cause i want to do this for thousands of objects and i also tried selecting and couldn't make it working.

New Blender 2.8 API is so confusing, after hours of searching all forums i can not find any way to make it work. This should be fairly easy task but seems to be impossible for some reason. I'm a newbie, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i found the answer:

Since `bpy.ops.object.convert()` needs a context the only way i managed it to work is:

```
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE')
```

Though, it's quite weird that i have to 'manually' select an object to be able to use it, why not just `obj.convert()`? I'm not sure if method i used is the only one possible but i tried A LOT of stuff.

**If there is a better, more elegant and robust method, please let me know!**

Blender API changes so fast that it took me couple of hours to find the answer, even [Blender 2.81 Docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html) were saying

> bpy.context.object = obj will raise an error.
>
> But
>
> bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj will work as expected.

While `bpy.context.scene.objects.active` is already deprecated!